# ChromeDriver fake Webcam unable to use provided FIle

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

I write UI Tests using selenium and chromedriver. And I need a Fake Webcam to scan an QRCode.

I am starting the Browser like this:

```cs
        public static IWebDriver driver;

        private static ChromeOptions GetChromeOptions()
        {
            ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
            option.AddArgument("start-maximized");
            option.AddArgument("disable-infobars");
            option.AddArgument("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream"); // automatically allows browser to use webcam
            option.AddArgument("use-fake-device-for-media-stream"); // uses a different webcam than the real one
            option.AddArgument(@"use-file-for-fake-video-capture=D:\Source\AURIS TIFOP SandBox\UITestingRetailApp\RetailAppTest\RetailAppTest\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\QRcode.mjpeg"); // uses File instead of default fake wbcam
            return option;
        }

        public static void OpenBrowser()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver(".", GetChromeOptions());
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Properties.IMPLICITWAIT);
        }
```

But when I go to https://de.webcamtests.com/ to test my Webcam it is not able to detect any Video input.

When removing the last Argumentline https://de.webcamtests.com/ shows a green default fake webcam.

Did I use wrong arguments or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

I've also been having the same issues with my QR code tests. I've tried instead a y4m file instead of mjpeg (can convert with ffmpeg) and had some luck seeing the mocked video stream. However, this isn't the ideal solution since it's such a large file and I can't upload it to GitHub.

Hope there's a solution for using a mjpeg file since my tests were working before but I'm not sure why not anymore. I am setting it up like you are.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug in Chrome v.92. My tests failed with .mjpeg video, but with .y4m works fine

Comment: Here is the bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1232499